# Using multiple database from Pleak/MyPhpAdmin (windows)

Tags: database, windows, plesk

I am currently using a hosting provider that has Pleak 11/phpMyAdmin 3.5 and I am trying to use two databases.

I have cloned my main database and created a db_beta, but I can not see this in phpmyadmin, but in plesk I have 2 out of 10 databases used!

Does anyone know what to change and where to change it.

I have rdp access to the windows box, so in theory I should be able to change any config.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean you can't see two databases?

In common case, in Plesk you have db user which has privileges for only one database.
When you click on db admin button in Plesk you enter in phpMyAdmin under one exact user which has access only in one exact database.

If you need enter in another database you have to click on db admin button for this database.

Plesk don't supports multiple databases for single db user. You can override it by granting privileges to db user for another databases directly in MySQL.